# Find a number in an Excel sheet's Column A and add the value to Column B

Tags: c#

Here is my problem:

[image: Excel Sheet]

I want to search for a value in column "A" using textbox1 
With textbox2 I need the value on the same row but in column "B".

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup()` is available in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. [More Info Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup?view=excel-pia)

Answer (score 0):

You can user third party library [Excel Data Reader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader), and go through how to use section as well as, how to read data using reader into a C# ADO DataSet. Then use row filters on associated DataView with the DataSet.

```
DataSet result= reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                    {
                        ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                        {
                            UseHeaderRow = true,
                            ReadHeaderRow = (rowReader) =>
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    });
```